# Is online gambling illegal in the United States?

Tags: united-states, gambling

> In the case of [United States v. Scheinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Scheinberg), against the founders
>   of the three largest online poker companies, PokerStars, Full Tilt
>   Poker and Cereus (Absolute Poker/Ultimatebet), and a handful of their
>   associates, which alleges that the defendants violated the Unlawful
>   Internet Gambling Enforcement Act (UIGEA) and engaged in bank fraud
>   and money laundering in order to process transfers to and from their
>   customers.

Does this mean that gambling online is illegal in the United States?

Comment: The case wasn't focused on online gambling (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Scheinberg#Convictions).

Comment: Or for a general overview see [**Which states allow online gambling?**](http://gamblingfaq.net/which-states-allow-online-gambling/) and [**States Considering Online Gambling**](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/govbeat/wp/2014/02/05/at-least-10-states-expected-to-consider-allowing-online-gambling-this-year/)

Comment: It means that the US Attorney was alleging that those 3 companies were violating the law.  But the facts are spelled out in the wiki article you linked.  What is it you do not understand?

Comment: Online gambling crossing state lines is illegal in the US by federal wire laws. Within a state, it's a state matter.